# Deliver temporary build-time assets with nuget

Tags: nuget

What is the proper way of delivering temporary build-time assets using nuget?

I am making a nuget package with a single file, which dependent projects require during the build phase. I would like the content of the file to be copied to `obj\$(Configuration)` folder inside a dependent project before proceeding with the rest of the build. Of course, the `obj` folder is temporary, so I would like my file to be copied there again as part of the next build if `obj` gets cleared out.

I tried `contentFiles` approach described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/). This takes care of packaging my file inside nupkg file, but I was unable to set it up so that my file gets delivered (and re-delivered) to `obj\$(Configuration)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [NuGet's MSBuild extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package). Unfortunately it means you'll need to learn a bit about MSBuild if you don't already know it. I recommend running `msbuild -bl` or `dotnet build -bl`, which will create a msbuild.binlog file, which you can view with the [msbuild structured log viewer](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog/releases).

One option is to have a target that creates the file in the intermediate output directory at an appropriate time (probably need to use BeforeTargets). You could use the Inputs and Outputs attributes to have msbuild do incremental build checks and skip copying when it doesn't need to, possibly making the build a little faster.

However, unless the file is has dynmanic content, copying the file is a waste. it's just going to be included as an item in another part of the build process. So, if it's static content, you could just create the relevant item in your targets file from your package's extracted directory, and then it's just as good as if it was copied to the intermediate output directory, without wasted time and duplicated disk space.